# If thou forgettest Me one day, I will forget thee two days

Tags: history, jewish-books, text, archaeology

In [a class](https://www.yutorah.org/sidebar/lecture.cfm/732090/dr-shnayer-leiman/dead-sea-scrolls/) he gave in the 90s, Rabbi Prof. Shnayer Leiman said that he believes that once all of the fragments of the Dead Sea Scrolls are properly analyzed and made public, it is very likely that the verse "אם תעזבנו יום יומים אעזבך - If thou forgettest Me one day, I will forget thee two days", which the [Yerushalmi](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Jerusalem_Talmud_Berakhot.68a.1?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) and the [Sifrei](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sifrei_Devarim.48.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=bi) quote in the name of a text called "Megillat Chasssidim", will be found among the fragments (9:28-10:45).

Does anyone know whether it was indeed found?

Comment: Presumably not because as of this writing Megilas Chasidim is not one of the scrolls found in the Dead Sea Scrolls

Comment: Isn't it in Ben Sira?

Comment: @Schmerel Maybe it's called something else by researchers? Or maybe it appears on a fragment, not a whole scroll?

Comment: @Shalom It didn't sound like that from Rabbi Leiman (he mentioned Ben-Sira several times and said that this verse came from a scroll mentioned by the Yerushalmi), but if you're aware that it's in Ben-Sira then I'd be happy to see.